# Does the Drcrobot urdf model have pressure, bumper, force or contact sensors?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello
I would like to know the answer for the next 3 questions:
1.Does the Drcrobot  urdfmodel have  pressure, bumper, force or contact sensors?
2. Does the Drcrobot  urdfmodel have   pressure, bumper, force or contact sensors in the feet?
3. what are the line(S),in the urdf model file ,where i can see those sensors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/947/does-the-drcrobot--urdf-model-have-pressure,-bumper,-force-or-contact-sensors?/) by [Jey_316](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/165/jey_316/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Go to the end of the file and you'll see the answer to all your questions (question 1 is a generalization of question 2, not sure what you're looking for ... the robot also has force torque sensors in the ankles and wrists but those aren't available in the release version  yet. The iRobot and Sandia hands have tactile and other sensors as well but those aren't implemented yet).

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1